# Can an EU citizen resident of NY drive in WA on their EU license?

Tags: usa, driving-license

Assume a person who’s a citizen of Germany and has a German driving license. They’re on an H-1B visa living in NY. NY requires them to exchange their license within 30 days so they can’t drive there after a month on their EU license.

But… what about other states? Can they drive in Washington or other states on their EU license?

Comment: "They’re on an H1-B visa living in NY. NY requires them to exchange their license within 30 days" NY only requires people who are domiciled in NY (defined as living there "with the intention of making it a fixed and permanent abode") to get a NY driver's license. Is an H1b worker considered domiciled in NY?

Comment: @user102008 if you ask the Federal government the answer is No. But NY law is separate so I have no idea.

Comment: @JonathanReez there is no federal purpose for which an H-1B worker cannot be considered domiciled in New York.

Comment: @phoog back when you still had to fill out the paper immigration forms when arriving into the US, H1Bs were explicitly told not to put down USA as their "country of residence".

Comment: @JonathanReez that's absurd.  But even if it was correct, it does not justify a statement such as "if you ask the Federal government the answer is No" since there are many areas of federal law in which such a person assuredly is a US resident.  Prominent among these is income taxation.

Comment: What is an EU license? As far as I know drivers licenses are issued by a *country*. And depending on country and their regulations, you will need an international drivers license on top of your local one, that can be issued for an administrative fee. In my (EU) country, we accept drivers licenses from different US states under different conditions, so I would not be surprised if different US states did the same with European countries' licenses. So I would be very surprised if the answer for a "unnamed EU license" is "it depends".

Comment: @nvoigt German license but US states actually don’t care at all when it comes to students driving. It only matters when exchanging your license.

Answer (score 1):

You can drive in WA on a foreign license as long as you're not a WA resident. If you do move to WA - you've got 30 days to get a local driving license. There's no law that requires that foreign license to be issued by a US state necessarily, and WA recognizes German licenses and [allows to directly exchange them into local licenses on establishing residency](https://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/moving.html) (as opposed to any other EU country).

You *may* run into some additional requirements when renting cars with a foreign license - I've been asked to also present a passport with I-94 in some cases. But other than that it shouldn't be any problem.

Not necessarily related to your question, but keep in mind that if your driving privileges were taken away by a court order, then **all** your licenses are invalid, even if you didn't let the court know you have a foreign one.

Comment: There _is_ a law requiring the license to be issued by the "home country" or "home state," however: https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=46.20.025 so if the EU citizen is a citizen of France with a German license it might not be sufficient.  This is rather vague, of course, and unlikely to come up in practice.  The opposite situation is more tenuous, however (a German-licensed resident of WA in NY), because New York [requires nonresidents to comply with driver licensing laws in the jurisdiction where they reside](https://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2022/vat/title-2/article-3/250/).

Comment: @phoog define "home". The OP is German, and in the US on a temporary visa. I'd argue that even under the strictest of interpretations the OP has a pretty good chance in court. Similarly in the opposite situation - if the OP never drives in WA, thus never needing WA driving license, then they're technically compliant.

Comment: It's not for me to define "home"; it's for the legislature of Washington State.  I am considering a modified hypothetical in which the driver consistent with the question title in which the driver is a citizen of a different EU country from that which issued the driver's license.  I agree that the driver has a pretty good chance in court, and I'd go even farther to say that the driver has a pretty good chance of not getting to court in the first place ("unlikely to come up in practice").

Comment: The argument about being compliant with Washington law by never driving in Washington is interesting, but I'm not convinced, since it would also apply to someone who has never held any driver's license but never drives in the jurisdiction there they reside.  I doubt that would stand up in court.

Comment: I prefer to answer realistic questions actual expatriates and travelers need help with and not deal with hypothetical what-ifs. There's law@SE for that.

Comment: Some people in situations similar to this question, myself included, want to understand what the law actually says and what extreme possibilities might come to pass along with the likelihood of their actually coming to pass.  In the event that a cop stops me and takes exception to my license because it's not issued in my place of residence, I want to have a coherent explanation ready.

Comment: @phoog in the event a cop stops you and takes exception to your license I suggest having a lawyer ready and going to the traffic court. Have yet to meet a person to successfully convince a cop that they're wrong.

Comment: Well the problem with that approach in this case is that a resident of NY or Washington is unlikely to be able to justify going to traffic court in the other state.  I agree that I'm unlikely to be able to change an officer's mind once it's made up, but presumably before that point there will be the question "why do you have a [German] license when you live in [New York]," and the answer might steer the conversation (and the cop's assessment of the situation) one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the New York law: [VAT section 250](https://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2022/vat/title-2/article-3/250/)

> 2 . A person of the age of sixteen years and upwards  who  shall  be
> a   nonresident of this state, and a resident of a state, territory,
> federal   district  or  foreign  country  having  laws, with which
> such person has   complied, which require such person, in order to
> operate a motor vehicle   or motorcycle therein, to be licensed, may
> operate  or  drive  a  motor   vehicle or motorcycle on the public
> highways of this state without being   so  licensed under this
> chapter, [...].  A  nonresident  entitled  to   operate  a  motor
> vehicle  or  motorcycle  as herein provided who shall   become a
> resident of this state may operate or drive a motor vehicle  or
> motorcycle  on  the  public  highways  of  this  state  for a period
> not   exceeding thirty days from the date he becomes a  resident
> pending  the   obtaining  of  a  license to operate such motor vehicle
> or motorcycle in   this state.
>
> 5 .  As  used  in  this  section,  the  term  "resident"   shall
> mean   domiciliary,  that is, one who lives in this state with the
> intention of   making it a fixed and permanent abode. It shall be
> presumptive  evidence   that  a person who maintains a place of abode
> in this state for a period   of at least ninety days is a resident of
> this state.

So just because you are "living" in New York does not mean you cannot drive on your out-of-state or foreign license, as long as you do not have the intention of making New York "a fixed and permanent abode".

Here is the Washington state law: [RCW 46.20.025](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=46.20.025)

> The following persons may operate a motor vehicle on a Washington
> highway without a valid Washington driver's license:
>
> (2) A nonresident driver who is at least:
>
> (a) Sixteen years of age and has immediate possession of a valid
> driver's license issued to the driver by his or her home state; or
>
> (b) Fifteen years of age with:
>
> (i) A valid instruction permit issued to the driver by his or her home
> state; and
>
> (ii) A licensed driver who has had at least five years of driving
> experience occupying a seat beside the driver; or
>
> (c) Sixteen years of age and has immediate possession of a valid
> driver's license issued to the driver by his or her home country. A
> nonresident driver may operate a motor vehicle in this state under
> this subsection (2)(c) for up to one year;

It doesn't define "home state" or "home country", but since it is in the context of "nonresidents", it probably refers to the state or country you are a "resident" of. Washington state defines "resident" for the purposes of getting a Washington state driver's license in [RCW 46.20.021](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=46.20.021) as

> (3) For the purposes of obtaining a valid driver's license, a resident is a person who manifests an intent to live or be located in this state on more than a temporary or transient basis.

Assuming that it considers the residence the same way for nonresidents as for its own driver's license, this means that the home state/country would be the one where you have an "intent to live on more than a temporary or transient basis". If you do not have such an intent in New York and have such an intent in Germany, then I would argue that you can drive with your German driver's license in Washington state (as well as New York state).

Comment: New York considers residence in the state for 90 days "presumptive evidence" of intent to maintain a fixed and permanent abode in the state.  Anyone who drives on a foreign license after living for more than 90 days in New York should expect that if they are stopped by a police officer in New York they will receive a summons for driving without a valid license and that they will have to challenge the charge in court.  Whether an H-1B worker would be successful in that challenge probably depends on individual circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a lawyer, so I looked at this NY Department of Motor Vehicles page: https://dmv.ny.gov/more-info/resources-non-us-citizens

My interpretation - apologies if I mis-understood something.

A person with H1B work visa doesn't *have to* get a  NY license to drive. But, if they want to, they *can* get a **NY license that says "Temporary Visitor"**. To me, this sounds like the easiest solution.

They can also drive legally with their foreign license, as long as they like. But because their license is printed not in English, but in German, therefore they must also carry either an **International Driving Permit** or a **certified translation** of their license. These would not be needed if the foreign license had been in English.

> NY requires them to exchange their license within 30 days

I'm ptetty sure that this isn't quite true, but please refer to the linked web page rather than rely on my interpretation.

Although not *required*, this sounds like the easiest route.

> they can’t drive there after a month on their EU license.

I'm ptetty sure that this isn't quite true either. It doesn't matter if this is their first month in NY. If they do drive, and a cop asks to see their license, and they don't have one of the 3 documents **highlighted** above, then they may get in trouble for driving without a license.

Answer (score -1):

There is a principle of reciprocation. Check out the following list, you will find all the states there:

https://stadt.muenchen.de/dam/jcr:6d37d7a7-5d03-4b21-88bc-007c73cc5849/Staatenliste-1.pdf

If your state is not there, bad luck on exchanging it there. BUT, you can still drive it one state's license anywhere in USA.

Comment: It's not about exchanging the license, it's about driving on the EU license while being an NY resident.